# SQL running total group by id and limited by a condition (over window)

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, window-functions

I'm having the following data in an SQL table. See [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28cc4f/13) for playing around.

| id | pointsEarned | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 234-00000206-0 | 500 | 2023-05-03T09:05:05.034Z |
| 234-00000206-0 | 1000 | 2023-05-12T09:05:05.034Z |
| 234-00000206-0 | 800 | 2023-05-15T09:05:05.034Z |
| 234-00000206-0 | 300 | 2023-05-21T09:05:05.034Z |
| 234-00000206-0 | 1100 | 2023-05-28T09:05:05.034Z |

The data is created as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE activities (
  id varchar(14),
  pointsEarned int,
  createdAt varchar(24)
  );
  
INSERT INTO activities (id, pointsEarned, createdAt)
VALUES ('234-00000206-0', 500, '2023-05-03T09:05:05.034Z');

INSERT INTO activities (id, pointsEarned, createdAt)
VALUES ('234-00000206-0', 1000, '2023-05-12T09:05:05.034Z');

INSERT INTO activities (id, pointsEarned, createdAt)
VALUES ('234-00000206-0', 800, '2023-05-15T09:05:05.034Z');

INSERT INTO activities (id, pointsEarned, createdAt)
VALUES ('234-00000206-0', 300, '2023-05-21T09:05:05.034Z');

INSERT INTO activities (id, pointsEarned, createdAt)
VALUES ('234-00000206-0', 1100, '2023-05-28T09:05:05.034Z');
```

From that data I'm looking for those IDs that have passed 1.000 points and at what date that has happened. In the sample data this would have been May 12th in the second line already.

I tried this SQL statement, but here the result is of course May, 28th.

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  SUM(pointsEarned) as points, 
  MAX(createdAt) as lastActivity
FROM 
  activities
GROUP BY
  id
HAVING 
  points > 1000;
```

Then I was thinking about using window functions and tried this one, but getting an error that the statement is wrong. Any idea how to fix the error (see SQL fiddle link above) and how to limit that query to 1.000 points?

```
SELECT 
  id,
  SUM(pointsEarned) OVER(ORDER BY createdAt) points
FROM activities;
```

PS: the SQL fiddle uses MySQL. Finally, I need the statement for Google BigQuery though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't work in MySQL 5.6 because in that version of MySQL window functions were not yet a feature available. Furthermore, you shouldn't test on MySQL if you need a Google Bigquery solution, because they're two deeply different products with different tools.

Given these premises, in Google Bigquery you have availability of the `QUALIFY` clause, that allows you to filter over the result of window functions. You can use qualify twice to check:

- when the running sum of points is higher than 1000
- when the date corresponds to the first date of your filtered running sum

by partitioning on "*id*" (assuming you can have multiple ids), and ordering on your date.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, 
           SUM(pointsEarned) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY createdAt) AS runningPoints, 
           createdAt
    FROM activities
    QUALIFY runningPoints > 1000
)
SELECT id, runningPoints, createdAt 
FROM cte 
QUALIFY createdAt = MIN(createdAt) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY runningPoints)
```

This answer was tested on Bigquery and gave the following output:

| id | runningPoints | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 234-00000206-0 | 1500 | 2023-05-12T09:05:05.034Z |

Comment: Hi. Sure you are right that Big Query is something else than MySQL. I thought it's a rather common problem that I'm trying to solve which might be answered using standard SQL. Many thanks for your answer. PS: I'm wondering how many data rows are processed if a large portion of data is >1000 points (first select statement) and then filtered by the second. Or if the SQL compiler is optimizing the statement to break earlier.

Comment: The DBMS will optimize your solution for your use case. Using window functions is typically the most efficient approach you can have, if it's available. Note that when you use a solution that can work across multiple databases, either it's a very simple solution, or it's not a DBMS-optimized solution.

Comment: Also you can't do it without subqueries in Bigquery, because one window function checks on the result of another window function. Other DBMS', like PosgreSQL or SQL Server, Oracle too, could have allowed no subqueries for that though, with some specific tool available in those environments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation. Your solutions works perfectly and it includes grouping by IDs. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished by first using the window function `sum()` with an `order by` clause to obtain the running total, followed by `row number()` to assign an id to each row ordered by the generated running total, then select only the row with rn = 1 :

```
with cte as (
  SELECT *, SUM(pointsEarned) over (partition by id order by createdAt) points
  FROM activities 
),
cte2 as (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by points) as rn
  from cte
  where points > 1000
)
select id, createdAt
from cte2
where rn = 1
```

To get data of a specific id then :

```
with cte as (
  SELECT *, SUM(pointsEarned) over (order by createdAt) points
  FROM activities 
  where id = '234-00000206-0'
),
cte2 as (
  select *, row_number() over (order by points) as rn
  from cte
  where points > 1000
)
select id, createdAt
from cte2
where rn = 1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/PI1PPEyz)

Comment: Nice. Thank you. Before I'm excepting any answer, I'm waiting if their is any solution in which the first SELECT does not yield ALL rows above the threshold before that subset is then filtered by the second condition.

Comment: PS: this code works as well, but you need to add grouping (partitioning) by IDs.

Answer (score 2):

You can express this in a single pass, with a single window function call. In BigQuery:

```
select a.*, 
    sum(pointsEarned) over(partition by id order by createdAt) as runningPoints, 
from activities a
qualify runningPoints >= 1000 and runningPoints - pointsEarned < 1000
```

The `qualify` clause identifies the row where the running sum reaches the threshold.

Note: this works as long as you don't have negative `pointsEarned`, as shown in your data (otherwise the query would bring one row for each occurence where the threshold is reached again).

Comment: Nice idea, too.

Answer (score 1):

You kind of answered this yourself, your SQL was valid (maybe you used an old version of MYSQL in your fiddle)

```
SELECT 
  id,
  SUM(pointsEarned) OVER(ORDER BY createdAt) points
FROM activities;
```

which yields

**Result (MySQL v8.0)**

| id | pointsEarned | createdAt | points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 234-00000206-0 | 500 | 2023-05-03T09:05:05.034Z | 500 |
| 234-00000206-0 | 1000 | 2023-05-12T09:05:05.034Z | 1500 |
| 234-00000206-0 | 800 | 2023-05-15T09:05:05.034Z | 2300 |
| 234-00000206-0 | 300 | 2023-05-21T09:05:05.034Z | 2600 |
| 234-00000206-0 | 1100 | 2023-05-28T09:05:05.034Z | 3700 |

now you only need to select the first row having > 1000 total points like this

```
SELECT sum_t.id, sum_t.createdAt
FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(pointsEarned) OVER(ORDER BY createdAt) points
    FROM activities
) as sum_t
WHERE sum_t.points > 1000
LIMIT 1
```

which leads to the following result

**Result (MySQL v8.0)**

| id | createdAt |
| --- | --- |
| 234-00000206-0 | 2023-05-12T09:05:05.034Z |

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ewHuBV4ju25W2sZ9wjRpUY/3)

Comment: Nice. Thank you. Before I'm excepting any answer, I'm waiting if their is any solution in which the first SELECT does not yield ALL rows above the threshold before that subset is then filtered by the second condition.

Comment: PS: this code works as well, but you need to add grouping (partitioning) by IDs.